# Cannot upgrade pip in Ubuntu VM on OS X Sierra

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, virtualization, pip

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a VM created by VirtualBox on OS X Sierra. After I installed some packages using `pip`, I got a prompt:

> You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command

Since I cannot copy from the VM and paste here, I have included am image of what happens when I run `pip install --upgrade pip`

[image: Output of <code>pip upgrade</code>]

How can I upgrade `pip` to the latest version, 9.0.1?

Answer (score 2):

You should run the `pip` command using `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

However I suggest you to install python packages using `--user` switch it's more safe in my opinion.

```
pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

After updating you can remove old version installed by `apt`:

```
sudo apt remove python-pip
```

or if it's for python3:

```
sudo apt remove python3-pip
```

At the end use `--version` to check `pip` version:

```
pip --version
```

Comment: Don't remove the version installed by apt! Because Ubuntu relies heavily on Python, things might break in horrible ways.

Comment: Nothing will happen. I didn't suggest to remove python. removing pip doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu. It's not even pre-installed :-)